# @Bean method requires to return null conditionally

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-saml2

I have basic authentication enabled in my system and now I am trying to integrate the SAML auth using Spring-security-SAML. I have created a method that returns the `RelyingPartRegistrationRepository` bean. In a condition While the user-configured values are not sufficient to Create the `RelyingPartRegistration`, I would have to either create a RelyingPartRegistrationRepository with Empty array which is not possible because there are checks to be not empty. another option is to return null from the Bean method. which is also a failure case because context initialization will fail in that case. All I want is to either not initialize this bean or at least not prevent context initialization. So that I can at least switch back to Basic Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@ConditionalOn...` to selectively enable/disable particular beans, based on things like properties

```
class MyConfiguration {
  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "saml-enabled", havingValue = "true")
  public RelyingPartRegistrationRepository() { ... }
}
```

See [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditionalonproperty) on Baeldung, and [another article](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-conditionals/) which covers a few other conditionals which may be useful, and of course the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.developing-auto-configuration.condition-annotations).